# Как определить ширину textarea на основе содержимого?

Tags: html, css

Есть textarea и атрибут value содержит текст.
Как указать textarea чтобы этот тэг растянулся по ширине?

Comment: а если текста много, все равно будете растягивать по ширине? [Пример решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize), [jsfiddle примера решения](http://jsfiddle.net/hmelenok/WM6Gq/)

Comment: с помощью js, естественно

Comment: Никаких новых css свойств не придумали для этого?

Comment: [mcve] добавьте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно **[документации W3](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)** тэг textarea не имеет атрибута value. Для растягивания содержимого этого тэга по длине браузера вы можете использовать следующие варианты:

- атрибут **rows** - проверьте изменение значений этого атрибута на **[инструменте W3 Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea)**;
- задать в стилях значение ширины в % для этого атрибута, например:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>textarea{width:100%}</style>
<body>
<textarea>
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```